# Best Way to Handle Quantity & Size

Tags: forms, information-architecture, e-commerce

I'm working on a project that helps businesses sell items online. Right now I'm trying to figure out a more intuitive way of handling the sizing and quantity of products. The common use case for adding products is for a shop to add a product without a size, but with a quantity. However, there are shops that need to sell items with a variation of sizes. In addition to this, the user will need to add variations for color, etc.

**Currently we have:**  [image]

I'm looking for a better means of solving for this problem, but I don't want anything clunky like you see on most eCommerce experiences. Our goal is to allow shop owners to add products quickly and simply but be able to get more complex, only when they need it.

Edit: This is for the backend experience, not for the consumer-end.

Comment: Do you ask for an universal solution or inside some product group (i.e. shoes, shirts, etc.)?

Comment: Universal. There are no categories setup at this point, and each store could have their own sizes/have a custom product with no conventional size. Though what are you thinking?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You might want to consider this approach. Availability of stock is very important in eCommerce website as well which is missing from your question.

What you can do as suggested from the image above, we can display the size and availability of the product. Upon selection of size and add to cart, user will be brought to the shopping cart for them to update the quantity. It might require an additional screen or click, but the user experience for the simple interaction is highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid this is looking at the end-user (consumer) experience. My question is regarding the administrator-side. That is, the person entering the data.

Answer (score 1):

- On create present them with just one set of fields (price & stock
  field) and allow for any particulars to be covered in the
  description.
- Provide an option for the product to become more complex
- Allow them to define their own ways in which products might vary (variation types) with the available variations for each variation type, eg. colours, sizes
- Then when they select to make a product more complex allow them to choose from the definitions I mentioned just above, with each choice automatically calculating the combinations and outputting them
- Let them choose which of the variation values they want to remove, i.e. they might not do a product in red, so choosing to remove this will remove all combinations with red in them
- Also allow for price, stock values etc to be set for all combinations listed, with the option to set them individually if required

This will allow for the user to generate many user-defined combinations of options for a product without typing each one in or creating them all individually. It's an interface that requires learning, but once configured could be very powerful.

finally:

Provide good customer support and answer questions promptly. Be prepared to help and take into account the resources you will need for this.